# Cross chain smartcontract interaction

Tags: cross-chain

I'm thinking about a particular use case where a smart contract in a private chain could send txs to the public chain (in my case txs would be functions calls of a smart contract in the public network).
In my knowledge it may not possible without passing through a server side interaction acting as a proxy between the two networks(too much centralized) but I hope that there's some implementation that I still don't know.

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

The ways for two blockchains to communicate

- A centralised server
- All private blockchain nodes fully sync with public chain and the public chain is used for communications
- Using some not yet existing solution like Cosmos hub and [Interblockchain communication](https://cosmos.network/ibc)